# How to make these icons do not appear on top of the Navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a row of three icons. What im trying to do is make the row of icons pass underneath the navigation bar which sticks on top of the webpage.

when the row of icons is about to pass the navigation bar i appears on top.

What im trying to achieve is make the row of icons pass under the navigation bar.

**HTML**

```
<section class="sub-banner row-fluid pad-top-extra pad-bottom-extra hidden-sm">
       <div class="container main">

         <ul class="ch-grid">
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item">       
              <div class="ch-info">
                <div class="ch-info-front ch-img-1"></div>
                <div class="ch-info-back">
                  <h3>Rest</h3>
                  <p>Everybody needs rest, and so do I.</p>
                </div>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <div class="ch-info-front ch-img-2"></div>
                <div class="ch-info-back">
                  <h3>Gym</h3>
                  <p>Enough rest = Power to Lift!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="ch-item">
              <div class="ch-info">
                <div class="ch-info-front ch-img-3"></div>
                <div class="ch-info-back">
                  <h3>Code</h3>
                  <p>"Go back to reality"</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>


        </div>
      </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.ch-grid {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;

}

.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.ch-grid:after {
    clear: both;
}

.ch-grid li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}


.ch-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-perspective: 900px;
    -moz-perspective: 900px;
    -o-perspective: 900px;
    -ms-perspective: 900px;
    perspective: 900px;
}
.ch-info{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.ch-info > div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.ch-info .ch-info-front {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ch-info .ch-info-back {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,-220px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,-220px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,-220px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,-220px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,-220px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0;
}

.ch-img-1 { 
    background-image: url(../css/deb2.png);


}

.ch-img-2 { 
    background-image: url(../css/gymicon.png);

}

.ch-img-3 { 
    background-image: url(../css/syntax.png);

}

.ch-info h3 {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    padding: 60px 0 0 0;
    height: 110px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 
        0 0 1px #fff, 
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ch-info p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.ch-info p a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    font-family:"Open_Sans_R";
}

.ch-info p a:hover {
    color: #fff222;
    color: rgba(239,65,53, 0.8);
}

.ch-item:hover .ch-info-front {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,280px,0) rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,280px,0) rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,280px,0) rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,280px,0) rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg);
    transform: translate3d(0,280px,0) rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

.ch-item:hover .ch-info-back {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post a version of your code including the sticky bar, the only scenario i can think of is the `z-index` value.

For a simple test, set `z-index: 1000;` to the sticky bar, and `z-index: 1;` to the icons that should hide under it.